# How can i bind two serializers into separate one serializer django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms

**info**: One is User and the Second one is User Data like phone number,city etc
Now i can add these two serializer into third serializer and show all data in third one

**Problem**: now i want to create new Serializer Where i can combine both serializer attributes. but i don't understand how can i achieve to bind two serializer into different one and show all data?

**serializers.py**

```
class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ['email', 'phone']


class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ['city']
```

**Want to achieve**

```
class CombineSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        fields = ['email', 'phone', 'city']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply create an object of a `LocationSerializer` in your contact serializer. This approach will create a nested object of location serializer.

```
class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    location = LocationSerializer() #if the contact serializer have multiple city then just add `many=True` as an argument.

    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ['email', 'phone', 'location']
```

While listing the object will look like this -

```
{
    'email':'some@email.com',
    'phone':'00009999888', 
    'location':{
        'city':'some_city'
    }
}
```

However, if you want to have both objects as a nested object than in that case you can simply call the serializer in the `CombineSerializer` class. But here instead of using `serializers.ModelSerializer` you will have to use `serializers.Serializer` as no model is associated with it.

This is how you can achieve it -

```
class CombineSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    contact = ContactSerializer()
    location = LocationSerializer()
```

In this case while listing the object will look like this -

```
{
    'contact' : {
        'email' : 'some@email.com',
        'phone' : '00999887666'
    },
    'location' : {
        'city' : 'Some City'
    }
}
```